# Android Accelerometer - Dynamic Time Warping

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gesture-recognition

For a class project I need to recognise gestures using the accelerometer. 
I currently use an explicit method of if statements on the x, y and z values.

I've read that Dynamic Time Wrapping is a more efficient way as it checks for a match between a gesture and a previously stored gesture.

How would I go about coding this in Android as I can't seem to find anything online.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    final float alpha = (float) 0.8;

    // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
    gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
    gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

    // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
    linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
    linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

    float x1 =  linear_acceleration[0];
    float y1 =  linear_acceleration[1];
    float z1 =  linear_acceleration[2];

    x.setText("X: "+ x1);
    y.setText("Y: "+ y1);
    z.setText("Z: " + z1);

    if(y1 < -2 && z1 > 2)
    {
        action.setText("Phone Moved Forward!!");
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.forwardarrow);
    }
    else if(y1 < -2 && z1 < -2)
    {
        action.setText("Phone Moved Toward Face!!");
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.backarrow);
    }
    else if(y1 < -2 && x1 > 2)//y down, x up = left tilt
    {
        action.setText("Phone Titled Left!");
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.leftarrow);
    }
    else if(y1 < -2 && x1 < -2)//y down, x down = right tilt
    {
        action.setText("Phone Titled Right!");
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.rightarrow);
    }
    else
    {
        image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        action.setText("Stable");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've uploaded a repository to GitHub which demonstrates [an example](https://github.com/Cawfree/Dynamic-Time-Warping) of Dynamic Time Warping for acceleromter data; you might find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic time warping computes the distance between two time-series. You store a template for the comparison and use the actual move as candidate. If you use all channels, you will have three different time-series and distances. If the accumulated distance is under a specific threshold, the movement will be marked as recognized. The difficult part is that you have continuous time-series. It's hard to spot gestures. Nevertheless the algorithm finds the best alignment between two time-series.

The method `onSensorChanged` gives you a **single** point of the time-series. So you have to build a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) data structure (e.g. a queue) which stores all changes of the last second.

Maybe the FastDTW library is helpful: https://code.google.com/archive/p/fastdtw/